# Dealing with out-of-order messages stored in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

**Background**

In distributed systems messages can arrive in an out of order fashion. For example if message A is sent at time T1 and message B is sent at T2 there is a chance that B is received before A. This matters for example if A is a message such as "CustomerRegistered" and B is "CustomerUnregistered".

In other databases I'd typically write a tombstone if CustomerUnregistered is received for a customer that is not present in the database. I can then check if this tombstone exists when the CustomerRegistered message is received (and perhaps simply ignore this message depending on use case). I could of course do something similar with Datomic as well but I hope that maybe Datomic can help me so that I don't need to do this.

One potential solution I'm thinking of is this:

Can you perhaps retract a non-existing customer entity (CustomerUnregistered) and later when CustomerRegistered is received the customer entity is written at a time in history *before* the retraction? It would be neat (I think) if the `:db/txInstant` could be set to a timestamp defined in the message.

**Question**

How would one deal with this scenario in Datomic in an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general principle, do not let your application code manipulate `:db/txInstant`. `:db/txInstant` represents the time at which you *learned* a fact, not the time at which it happened.

Maybe you should consider un-registration as adding a Datom about a customer (e.g via an instant-typed `:customer/unregistered` attribute) instead of retracting the Datoms of that customer (which means: "forget that this customer existed").

However, if retracting the datoms of customer is really the way you want to do things, I'd use a record which prevents the customer registration transaction to take place (which I'd enforce via a transaction function).