# Use event time instead of transaction time in Datomic?

Tags: time, clojure, transactions, datomic

**Background**

I'm using Datomic to store projections of events generated by other systems (projections in this case can be regarded as an entity in Datomic). These events have a timestamp associated with them that tells when the event was (for example) created. This is obviously not the same as the transaction time that Datomic will assign to the transaction when it stores a new attribute (based on the event) in the projection. Users of my application are not interested in the transaction time but rather the event time. The reason why I'm using Datomic in the first place is to be able to get an entity (or query the database) as it were at a specific time. However this time should *not* be the Datomic transaction time but rather the event time. For example I want be able to get an entity based on this *event time*:

```
(datomic/entity (datomic/as-of db event-time) id)
```

**Possible solution**

One idea that I'm thinking of is to set `:db/txInstant` for each transaction to the event time but I've been [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938037/398441) not to do this as a general principle. Another potential problem with this is that you can't assign a `:db/txInstant` that is older than the schema (which *will* be the case in my application). A solution to this would be to set a really early `:db/txInstant` to the transaction creating the schema.

**Question**

How does one typically deal with event time rather than transaction time in Datomic? How does the "possible solution" hold up?

Answer (score 3):

In general, Datomic's transaction time (`t`) is intended to record when the system found out about a fact, not the domain time of the fact.

If you need to handle domain time (i.e. the time something occurred in the 'real world', or event time in your example), I'd strongly recommend modeling the domain time explicitly with an attribute (you can use an attribute of type `:db.type/instant`). This would allow you to set dates without any restriction as well as query both domain time and system time separately for questions like "when did X happen AND when did my database find out about X happening?".

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but how can I for example get an entity at a specific event time if I do this?

Comment: To clarify I mean that I'm interested to how the database looks like at a certain instant, and this instant should be the event time and not the Datomic processing/transaction time.

Comment: You can use `(d/as-of db date)` to get a view of the database at `date`, where date is a java.util.Date (which is what :db.type/instant resolves to)