# Retract entity with a certain db/txInstant set in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'd like to retract an entity and at the same time specify the `db/txInstant` attribute but I cannot get this to work. Retracting the entity looks like this (and this works):

```
[[:db.fn/retractEntity [:person/email "jdoe@example.com"]]]
```

I've tried various ways to also supply the `db/txInstant` attribute, for example:

```
[[:db.fn/retractEntity [:person/email "jdoe@example.com"]]
 [:db/txInstant <inst>]]
```

but this fails with:

```
Caused by: datomic.impl.Exceptions$IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo: :db.error/not-a-data-function Not a data function: 50
 at datomic.error$arg.invoke (error.clj:57)
    datomic.error$arg.invoke (error.clj:55)
    datomic.db.Db.getFn (db.clj:1794)
    datomic.db.ProcessExpander.inject (db.clj:2473)
    datomic.db.ProcessInpoint.inject (db.clj:2372)
    datomic.db$with_tx$inject_all__2222$fn__2223.invoke (db.clj:2535)
    clojure.lang.PersistentVector.reduce (PersistentVector.java:341)
    clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic (core.clj:6544)
    clojure.core$reduce.invoke (core.clj:6527)
    datomic.db$with_tx$inject_all__2222.invoke (db.clj:2535)
    datomic.db$with_tx.invoke (db.clj:2539)
    datomic.peer.LocalConnection/fn (peer.clj:557)
    datomic.peer.LocalConnection.transactAsync (peer.clj:557)
    datomic.peer.LocalConnection.transact (peer.clj:549)
    datomic.api$transact.invoke (api.clj:94)
    ....
```

So my question is simply how I can specify the `db/txInstant` attribute when retracting an entity in Datomic?

Comment: What is the use case for this? If you can find the entity you wish to retract by `:person/email`, then you don't need to also specify `:db/txInstant`.

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is to be able to later query for when an attribute was retracted. "When" should not be the system time of the server running Datomic but rather a time determined by the application. Thus I figure that I'd like to specify this as the txinstant time.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't how Datomic is meant to operate. The txInstant is just the current UTC time read from the computer clock whenever the transaction occurs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870000/retract-entity-with-a-certain-db-txinstant-set-in-datomic/#comment67062006_39884012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(d/transact conn [{:db/id        #db/id [:db.part/tx]
                   :db/txInstant #inst "2016-10-29"}
                  [:db.fn/retractEntity [:person/email "jdoe@example.com"]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

txInstant as I understand it is the time that the transaction specifying the change, be it retraction or addition, happened. So If you where to succeed in doing this you are essentially saying to the transactior:

"Hey there transactor please create a transaction now that happened sometime other then now"

Which would break all the other time semantics in the DB. Which is why we generally use namespaced keyswords in datomic.

**Instead of setting `:db/txInstant` set `:my.company.db/txInstant`**. That way you can find out both the time of the transaction as determined by your transaction and the rest of the system can determine when the transactor created the transaction, which will keep things like the event-stream happy.

Comment: I understand that this would be better, the problem is that I need to get the (history) database as it looked at :my.company.db/txInstant. I'm only aware that you can get the DB at :db/txInstant. I have a seperate question for this for which I haven't got a satisfactory answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287619/use-event-time-instead-of-transaction-time-in-datomic

Answer (score 0):

If you need to attach metadata to a transaction (such as why the tx occurred, or any related data), you can do so.  You can fine good info on the Datomic website:

http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html

http://blog.datomic.com/2015/12/reified-transactions.html

and a detailed video on this exact topic by Tim Ewald from the Nov 2015 Datomic conference (prelude to the Clojure Conj):

http://www.datomic.com/videos.html